# Type reuse in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to get the type `Shape` to re-use the types `Circle` and `Rectangle`

```hs
data Point = Point {
    x :: Float,
    y :: Float
} deriving (Show)

data Circle = Circle {
    c :: Point,
    r :: Float
} deriving (Show)

data Rectangle = Rectangle {
    p1 :: Point,
    p2 :: Point
} deriving (Show)

-- the following obviously doesn't compile
data Shape = Circle Circle | Rectangle Rectangle deriving (Show)
```

The above leads to the compilation errors

```
Multiple declarations of ‘Circle’
18 | data Shape = Circle Circle | Rectangle Rectangle deriving (Show)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
Multiple declarations of ‘Rectangle’
18 | data Shape = Circle Circle | Rectangle Rectangle deriving (Show)
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I declare a type `Shape` that would be a union of all possible different shapes (like `Circle` or `Rectangle`) so that I'm able to use them in subsequent functions like the following?

```
area :: Shape -> Float
area (Circle _ r) = pi * r * 2
area (Rectangle p1 p2) = abs (x p2 - x p1) * abs (y p2 - y p1)
```

Comment: You can't have two constructors with the same name. You could define those in different modules, but then you would need to disambiguate between them at every use. It's simpler to use different names.

Comment: You can not reuse the same data constructor. That is what the error is all about. One often works with a typeclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I declare a type `Shape` that would be a union of all possible different shapes (like `Circle` or `Rectangle`) so that I'm able to use them in subsequent functions like the following?

That would likely not be good design, since if later another person wants to add a shape, then that is not possible. Often one uses a [*type class* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). A typeclass is to some extent comparable to an *interface* in Java. Types can be "*members*" of a typeclass if they implement the methods the typeclass offers.

We can thus for example define a typeclass:

```
class Shape a where
    area :: a -> Float
```

Then `Circle` and `Rectangle` can implement this:

```
instance Shape Circle where
    area (Circle _ r) = 2 * pi * r

instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle p1 p2) = abs (x p2 - x p1) * abs (y p2 - y p1)
```

Here `area` has type `area :: Shape a => a -> Float`, it thus means that for every type `a` where `a` is a "member" of the `Shape` typeclass, you can obtain the area. A type class thus provides a form of *ad-hoc polymorphism*.

Comment: Then they inevitably will want to put different shapes in a list together, and before you know it, they will be using existential types! Think of the children!

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: well in that case, one can make a sumtype (or use `Either`) to combine. But the problem with using a data type `Shape` is that you "close" it. So extending it is no longer possible. For concepts like shapes, one can keep constructing new subsets of shapes.

Comment: Yeah I know. For the record, I don't really share the negative sentiment towards existential types (I'm not a real Haskeller to be honest).

Answer (score 5):

```
data Circle = Circle ... -- one
data Shape  = Circle ... -- two
```

You are trying to define two separate data constructors named `Circle`: one is for the data type `Circle` and the other is for the data type `Shape`. You can't do that in the same module (without some advanced language extensions at least). Rename one of the `Circle`s at the right hand side of the `=`. The data type at the left-hand side of the `=` can still be `Circle`, there is no conflict.